# How to retrieve user-agent value in javascript (Agent is not defined)?

Tags: javascript, node-red

I would like to retrieve the user-agent value from header but when I run my code it shows agent is not defined, which seems like the program is not able to recognise the '-'.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm using flow.json in Node Red, I am unable to access this.window. For my solution, for example if I want to get user-agent, instead of msg.req.headers.user-agent I use msg.req.headers['user-agent'].

Answer (score 0):

Use the `navigator` object

e.g: below:

```
navigator.userAgent;
```

See the Ref. [userAgent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)

Comment: There is no `navigator` object available on the server side in Node-RED.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
```

Comment: There is no `window` object available on the server side in Node-RED.